# if statement keeps falling back to the else part

Tags: php, cookies

I want to check if a cookie exist and if not look into the header if it is send with the link and if that is FALSE go back to the page where i create the cookie in the header. When i input this code into my code (on top)

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['location'])){
    if(isset($_GET['location'])){
        $_COOKIE['location'] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'loc', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        setcookie('location', $_COOKIE['location'], time()+3600 * 8);
    }
    else {
        header('Location: location-select');
    }
```

It keeps falling back to the else part `header('Location: location-select');` no matter what i try. If i remove this block of code it works fine but there is no check on my cookie. Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think you never set your cookie!

Comment: Have you `var_dump`'ed `$_COOKIE['location']` to make sure of its condition?

Comment: what is your goal actually with this lines of code? To check if the cookie is set and if yes to expand the life time and otherwise a header()?

Comment: There's a mismatch between what you call the GET var.  You check if 'location' is set, but grab if in filter_input with 'loc'. Could be your problem

Comment: @Sondre I could put my head into the sand. My problem was indead `if(isset($_GET['location']))` it had to be `if(isset($_GET['loc']))` instead. You know that is why you better stop an hour after allready coding 8 hours. Sorry for this stupid question...

Comment: you should test with isset() FIRST, especially since `empty()` can/will fail if your value naturally contains "falsey" values, like `0` or `''`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

It checks if `$_COOKIE['location']` is empty and isn't set.
If that's the case then it creates a cookie with the data you supplied.
If it /is/ set it navigates to `location-select`.

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['location'])){
    if( ! isset($_GET['location'])){
        $data = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'loc', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        setcookie('location', $data, time()+3600 * 8);
    }
    else {
        header('Location: location-select');
    }
}
```